# using "//?" to run javascript in Visual Studio code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

https://puu.sh/FRzbQ/15519a1399.png

https://puu.sh/FRzh1/88c911756f.png

I was watching a video, and he used "//?" after a line of code in vs code, and then it returned the expected value. But that does not work for me. All I get is this

https://puu.sh/FRzeI/1ac1ca1b40.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a pro feature of an Extension called Quokka: https://quokkajs.com/docs/index.html